# jsp is not working properly on all browsers

Tags: java, tomcat

I have developed a simple login application.with reference to http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/. I have redirected my login.jsp page to admin.jsp where I have my logout URL and  welcome admin heading.when I run my project in default browser it is working properly.

But when I copy the URL and paste it in another browser it is not displaying logout URL and heading. I have included my admin.jsp code in this.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Admin Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#from").datepicker({
                defaultDate : "+1w",
                changeMonth : true,
                numberOfMonths : 1,
                onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $("#to").datepicker({
                defaultDate : "+1w",
                changeMonth : true,
                numberOfMonths : 1,
                onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                    $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>


<body bgcolor="grey">

    <%-- <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1> --%>

    <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />

    </form>
    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
        </h2>
    </c:if>
        <label for="from">Start_Date : </label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="to">End_Date :  </label>
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/admin' />" method='POST'>

        <table>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it throw any exception

Comment: other than those logout url and welcome admin....everything which is there in the admin page is getting displayed in different browsers. can any one help me in this...why it is not displaying those things in browser. plz reply asap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no it din't throw any exception @ Saurabh Jhunjhunwala

Comment: Welcome admin|logout    start _date, end_date, submit out of these only start_date,end_date, submit only getting displayed in browsers other than default browser.

Comment: I guess pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name is null - do some server side debugging to find out why it is not being set.

Comment: can you try moving the <script> tag from <body> to <head>; you can also replace <script> with <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: The `<form` I would expect before the first `<label` - a paste error?

Comment: <script>
  function formSubmit() {
   document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
  }
 </script>  are you telling about this ??? @ Saurabh Jhunjhunwala

Comment: @ CodeRunner can you please explain me how to do that

Comment: Before years one would place the user-define script with jQuery code just before the `</body>` for portability/efficiency.

Comment: @ Joop Eggen Hi, it is just to display the start_date and end_date after the welcome title and logout url. i don think that error is there in that part.

Comment: @AspenSugan you might put them then inside their own `<form> </form>`. In some modes a start tag `<form>` maybe gets inserted.

Comment: Ok , let me try that and thank you@ Joop Eggen

Comment: i made all the changes which u all have told. but still it is not working. can anyone please help in this issue.